# Django create a dropdown from a database model and save in another model

Tags: python, django, dropdown

I am new to Django and Python and would like to attempt the following. Create a dropdown list from the data in a model and save the data in another model. However everytime I render the form, it is invalid and does not display the template, Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please help where I am going wrong.

Models.py:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    category = models.TextField(default = ' ')

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.category


class UserItem(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.category
```

Forms.py:

```
class DropDown(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField()
    parts = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Part.objects.values_list('category', flat=True).distinct())

    class Meta:
        model = UserItem
        fields = ('name', 'category',)
```

Views.py:

```
def index(request):
    query_results = Part.objects.all()
    #part_list = DropDown()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DropDown(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request,'index.html', {'query_results': query_results }, {'form': form } )

    else:
        print("invalid")
        print (DropDown.errors)
        form = DropDown()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('genre_create') )
```

Comment: Your form method is `POST` ?

Comment: For `GET` request, you are not returning any form.

Comment: @MKPatel : yes my form method is post. Let me post my template:                                          
    {% block content %}
    <form method=POST action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
      Name :    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
      Category: <select name ="category" id="category">
        {% for item in query_results %}
        <option value="{{ item.category }}">{{ item.category }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    {% endblock %}

Comment: @Ejaz : Could you point out the same please as I dont see any get here.

Answer (score 0):

In your `views.py`, update the last return statement to below-

```
return render(request, "index.html", 
    {'form': form, 'query_results': query_results})
```

You can check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view)

You can infact get rid of the `else` block -

```
def index(request):
    query_results = Part.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DropDown(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request,'index.html', {'query_results': query_results }, {'form': form } )

    form = DropDown()
    return render(request, "index.html", 
        {'form': form, 'query_results': query_results})
```

And, just because you have already created `form` in your python code, you don't need to write `html`s for select and other tags. You can refer this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options) on form rendering options.

Comment: @Ezaz : I used the below code to refer to the dropdown :                                               {% for item in query_results %} <option value="{{ item.category }}">{{ item.category }}</option> {% endfor %} </select>  So how should I refer to the dropdown if I am passing only form ? is there a way?

Comment: In your code above, if the request is not a `POST`, then you are only redirecting but not returning the form. That you have to update with my return statement.

Comment: I have made the changes as per your comment. Now the template is getting displayed, but the dropdown does not contain any data. category dropdown is blank. The Part table containing the category column has data though. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: my html is referring to query_results variable. But here it is going to else, hence query results is not displaying. why is my form invalid? the error message says <Property object at 0X0312....>

Comment: you have to return the query results as well. I have updated my answer.